# How can I make a variable as a key?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

How can I make a variable into a key or a value so that I can use it in `in_array()`?

For instance,

```
// set the variable
$cnt_firstname = trim($_POST['cnt_firstname']);
$required = trim($_POST['required']);

// set the array for required fields
$array_required = explode(' ',$required);

// check the item is not empty and if it is in the array of required
if(empty($cnt_firstname) && in_array($cnt_firstname, $array_required))
{
$error = true;
echo '<error elementid="cnt_firstname" message="Please enter your fist name." />';
}
```

this is the post data I would send from a form,

```
Array
(
    [cnt_firstname] =>
    [cnt_lastname] => 
    [cnt_organisation] => 
    [cnt_email1] => 
    [cnt_telephpne] => 
    [required] => cnt_firstname cnt_lastname cnt_email1
)
```

I cannot get the result. I want it to return false if the field is empty and that field is in required array.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I think you have a double negative logic twist somewhere. The value is **empty and** in the required array…? Do you mean **not empty**? Or **or**?

Comment: You should not be relying on information returned from a form to determine if a value is required. It's very easy for those values to be faked.

Comment: @deceze Got stuck on that first, too :) What he means: If the variable is empty, but required, empty = true AND also in the required-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick & Dirty:

```
if(empty($cnt_firstname) && in_array('cnt_firstname', $array_required))
```

The way you wrote it won't work, because it will only check, if $cnt_firstname is in the required array, if it's empty - in other words: is an empty string in array?